# Dropdown menu to select item inside the array and apply to equation Matlab app designer

Tags: matlab, runtime-error

for context I have a dropdown menu in my code that selects the diameter of a tube, for each different diameter I have a different loss of pressure in the line. I need this dropdown menu to set a position N, that can be used for setting the other variables for the calculation of loss of pressure, but every time I try I get a *"Error using matlab.ui.control.EditField/set.Value (line 99) 'Value' must be a character vector or a string scalar."* even seting N=1 or N=2...

I'm using Matlab app designer and I was expecting ther for in the line 77 to set the value N for the diâmetro selected on the drop down but it dose not

```
classdef Sistemas < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure                        matlab.ui.Figure
        EditField3                      matlab.ui.control.EditField
        EditField3Label                 matlab.ui.control.Label
        EditField2                      matlab.ui.control.EditField
        EditField2Label                 matlab.ui.control.Label
        EditField                       matlab.ui.control.EditField
        EditFieldLabel                  matlab.ui.control.Label
        DadosdeentradaButtonGroup       matlab.ui.container.ButtonGroup
        CalcularButton                  matlab.ui.control.Button
        PerdasdecargaButtonGroup        matlab.ui.container.ButtonGroup
        Image                           matlab.ui.control.Image
        Spinner_16                      matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_15                      matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_14                      matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_13                      matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_12                      matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_11                      matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_10                      matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_9                       matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_8                       matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_7                       matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_6                       matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_5                       matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_4                       matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_3                       matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner_2                       matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        Spinner                         matlab.ui.control.Spinner
        TubulaoButtonGroup              matlab.ui.container.ButtonGroup
        DiametrodatubulaoinDropDown     matlab.ui.control.DropDown
        DiametrodatubulaoinDropDownLabel  matlab.ui.control.Label
        Metal_Label                     matlab.ui.control.Label
        PVC_Label                       matlab.ui.control.Label
        Switch                          matlab.ui.control.Switch
        Diametro_haste_do_atuador       matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField
        DiametrohastedoatuadorinLabel   matlab.ui.control.Label
        Diametro_atuador                matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField
        DiametrodoatuadorinLabel        matlab.ui.control.Label
        Comprimento_recalque            matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField
        ComprimentorecalquemLabel       matlab.ui.control.Label
        Comprimento_suc                 matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField
        ComprimentosucomLabel           matlab.ui.control.Label
        Pressao_reservatorio            matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField
        PressaodesaidadabombaEditField  matlab.ui.control.Label
        Pressao_saida_bomba             matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField
        PressaodesaidadabombaEditFieldLable  matlab.ui.control.Label
        VazovolumetricamsEditField      matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField
        VazovolumetricamsEditFieldLabel  matlab.ui.control.Label
        FluidoButtonGroup               matlab.ui.container.ButtonGroup
        ViscosidadedofluidoEditField    matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField
        ViscosidadedofluidoEditFieldLabel  matlab.ui.control.Label
        TemperaturadeoperaoCEditField   matlab.ui.control.NumericEditField
        TemperaturadeoperaoCEditFieldLabel  matlab.ui.control.Label
    end

    
    
    methods (Access = private)
        
    end


    % Callbacks that handle component events
    methods (Access = private)

        % Button pushed function: CalcularButton
        function Calcular(app, event)

            Diamtubo = app.DiametrodatubulaoinDropDown.Value
            Mtubo = str2num(app.Switch.Value);
            Cs = app.Comprimento_suc.Value;
            
            Dtubo = ["0.75","1","1.25","1.5","2","2.5","3","4","5"];
            for i=1:length(Dtubo)
                if strcmp(Diamtubo,Dtubo(i))
                    N=i;
                    app.EditField.Value = N;
                end
            end
              
            switch  Mtubo
                
                case 0
                    
                    c90 = [0.5,0.6,0.7,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.9];%%%Curva 90graus
                    c45 = [0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,1.1]; %%%Curva 45graus
                    j90 = [1.2,1.5,2,3.2,3.4,3.7,3.9,4.3,4.9]; %%%Joelho 90graus
                    j45 = [0.5,0.7,1,1.3,1.7,2,2.5,3.4,4.2]; %%%Joelho 45graus
                    tpd = [0.8,0.9,1.5,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,3.3]; %%%Te de passagem direta
                    tsl = [2.4,3.1,4.6,7.3,7.6,7.8,8,8.3,10]; %%%Te de saida lateral
                    tsb = [2.4,3.1,4.6,7.3,7.6,7.8,8,8.3,10]; %%%Te de saida bilateral
                    u = [0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25]; %%%União
                    sc = [0.9,1.3,1.4,3.2,3.3,3.5,3.7,3.9,4.9]; %%%Saida de canalização
                    lr = [0.3,0.2,0.15,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.85,0.95,1.2]; %%%Luva de redução
                    rg = [0.2,0.3,0.4,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.9,1,1.1]; %%%Registro de gaveta
                    rga = [6.7,8.2,11.3,13.4,17.4,21,26,34,43]; %%%Registro de esfera aberto
                    raa = [3.6,4.6,5.6,6.7,8.5,10,13,17,21]; %%%Registro de angulo aberto
                    vpc = [9.5,13.3,15.3,18.3,23.7,25,26.8,28.8,37.4]; %%%Valvula de pé com crivo 
                    vrh = [1.6,2.1,2.7,3.2,4.2,5.2,6.3,6.4,10.4]; %%%Valvula de retenção Horizontal
                    vrv = [2.4,3.2,4.0,4.8,6.4,8.1,9.7,12.9,16.1]; %%%Valvula de retenção vertical
                
        %            app.EditField3.Value = Cs*(c90(N)*app.Spinner.Value+c45(N)*app.Spinner_2.Value+j90(N)*app.Spinner_3.Value...
        %                +j45(N)*app.Spinner_4.Value+tpd(N)*app.Spinner_5.Value+tsl(N)*app.Spinner_6.Value+tsb(N)*app.Spinner_7.Value+u(N)*app.Spinner_8.Value...
        %                +sc(N)*app.Spinner_9.Value+lr(N)*app.Spinner_10.Value+rg(N)*app.Spinner_11.Value+rga(N)*app.Spinner_12.Value+raa(N)*app.Spinner_13.Value...
        %               +vpc(N)*app.Spinner_14.Value+vrh(N)*app.Spinner_15.Value+vrv(N)*app.Spinner_16.Value);

                case 1
            
                    c90 = [0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9,1,1.3,1.6,2.1]; %%%Curva 90graus
                    c45 = [0.2,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.9]; %%%Curva 45graus
                    j90 = [0.7,0.8,1.1,1.3,1.7,2,2.5,3.4,4.2]; %%%Joelho 90graus
                    j45 = [0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.9,1.2,1.5,1.9]; %%%Joelho 45graus
                    tpd = [0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.6,2.1,2.7]; %%%Te de passagem direta
                    tsl = [1.4,1.7,2.3,2.8,3.5,4.3,5.2,6.7,8.4]; %%%Te de saida lateral
                    tsb = [1.4,1.7,2.3,2.8,3.5,4.3,5.2,6.7,8.4]; %%%Te de saida bilateral
                    u = [0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04]; %%%União
                    sc = [0.5,0.7,0.9,1,1.5,1.9,2.2,3.2,4]; %%%Saida de canalização
                    lr = [0.29,0.16,0.12,0.38,0.64,0.71,0.78,0.9,1.07]; %%%Luva de redução
                    rg = [0.1,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.4,0.5,0.7,0.9]; %%%Registro de gaveta
                    rga = [6.7,8.2,11.3,13.4,17.4,21,26,34,43]; %%%Registro de esfera aberto
                    raa = [3.6,4.6,5.6,6.7,8.5,10,13,17,21]; %%%Registro de angulo aberto
                    vpc = [5.6,7.3,10,11.6,14,17,22,23,30]; %%%Valvula de pé com crivo 
                    vrh = [1.6,2.1,2.7,3.2,4.2,5.2,6.3,6.4,10.4]; %%%Valvula de retenção Horizontal
                    vrv = [2.4,3.2,4.0,4.8,6.4,8.1,9.7,12.9,16.1]; %%%Valvula de retenção vertical
                    
                        
                    
        %             app.EditField3.Value = Cs*(c90(N)*app.Spinner.Value+c45(N)*app.Spinner_2.Value+j90(N)*app.Spinner_3.Value...
        %                +j45(N)*app.Spinner_4.Value+tpd(N)*app.Spinner_5.Value+tsl(N)*app.Spinner_6.Value+tsb(N)*app.Spinner_7.Value+u(N)*app.Spinner_8.Value...
        %                +sc(N)*app.Spinner_9.Value+lr(N)*app.Spinner_10.Value+rg(N)*app.Spinner_11.Value+rga(N)*app.Spinner_12.Value+raa(N)*app.Spinner_13.Value...
        %               +vpc(N)*app.Spinner_14.Value+vrh(N)*app.Spinner_15.Value+vrv(N)*app.Spinner_16.Value);
                    
            end       
            
        end
    end

    % Component initialization
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure and hide until all components are created
            app.UIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 1096 638];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'MATLAB App';

            % Create DadosdeentradaButtonGroup
            app.DadosdeentradaButtonGroup = uibuttongroup(app.UIFigure);
            app.DadosdeentradaButtonGroup.Title = 'Dados de entrada';
            app.DadosdeentradaButtonGroup.Position = [1 138 562 501];

            % Create FluidoButtonGroup
            app.FluidoButtonGroup = uibuttongroup(app.DadosdeentradaButtonGroup);
            app.FluidoButtonGroup.Title = 'Fluido';
            app.FluidoButtonGroup.Position = [195 346 198 135];

            % Create TemperaturadeoperaoCEditFieldLabel
            app.TemperaturadeoperaoCEditFieldLabel = uilabel(app.FluidoButtonGroup);
            app.TemperaturadeoperaoCEditFieldLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.TemperaturadeoperaoCEditFieldLabel.Position = [10 81 179 22];
            app.TemperaturadeoperaoCEditFieldLabel.Text = 'Temperatura de operação(ºC)';

            % Create TemperaturadeoperaoCEditField
            app.TemperaturadeoperaoCEditField = uieditfield(app.FluidoButtonGroup, 'numeric');
            app.TemperaturadeoperaoCEditField.Position = [9 59 180 22];
            app.TemperaturadeoperaoCEditField.Value = 25;

            % Create ViscosidadedofluidoEditFieldLabel
            app.ViscosidadedofluidoEditFieldLabel = uilabel(app.FluidoButtonGroup);
            app.ViscosidadedofluidoEditFieldLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.ViscosidadedofluidoEditFieldLabel.Position = [10 29 179 22];
            app.ViscosidadedofluidoEditFieldLabel.Text = 'Viscosidade do fluido';

            % Create ViscosidadedofluidoEditField
            app.ViscosidadedofluidoEditField = uieditfield(app.FluidoButtonGroup, 'numeric');
            app.ViscosidadedofluidoEditField.Position = [9 7 180 22];

            % Create TubulaoButtonGroup
            app.TubulaoButtonGroup = uibuttongroup(app.DadosdeentradaButtonGroup);
            app.TubulaoButtonGroup.Title = 'Tubulação';
            app.TubulaoButtonGroup.Position = [1 1 195 480];

            % Create VazovolumetricamsEditFieldLabel
            app.VazovolumetricamsEditFieldLabel = uilabel(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.VazovolumetricamsEditFieldLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.VazovolumetricamsEditFieldLabel.Position = [9 346 179 22];
            app.VazovolumetricamsEditFieldLabel.Text = 'Vazão volumetrica(m³/s)';

            % Create VazovolumetricamsEditField
            app.VazovolumetricamsEditField = uieditfield(app.TubulaoButtonGroup, 'numeric');
            app.VazovolumetricamsEditField.Position = [8 324 180 22];

            % Create PressaodesaidadabombaEditFieldLable
            app.PressaodesaidadabombaEditFieldLable = uilabel(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.PressaodesaidadabombaEditFieldLable.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.PressaodesaidadabombaEditFieldLable.Position = [9 243 179 22];
            app.PressaodesaidadabombaEditFieldLable.Text = 'Pressão de saida da bomba(Kpa)';

            % Create Pressao_saida_bomba
            app.Pressao_saida_bomba = uieditfield(app.TubulaoButtonGroup, 'numeric');
            app.Pressao_saida_bomba.Position = [8 221 180 22];

            % Create PressaodesaidadabombaEditField
            app.PressaodesaidadabombaEditField = uilabel(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.PressaodesaidadabombaEditField.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.PressaodesaidadabombaEditField.Position = [8 295 180 22];
            app.PressaodesaidadabombaEditField.Text = 'Pressão do reservatório(Kpa)';

            % Create Pressao_reservatorio
            app.Pressao_reservatorio = uieditfield(app.TubulaoButtonGroup, 'numeric');
            app.Pressao_reservatorio.Position = [8 273 180 22];

            % Create ComprimentosucomLabel
            app.ComprimentosucomLabel = uilabel(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.ComprimentosucomLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.ComprimentosucomLabel.Position = [8 191 180 22];
            app.ComprimentosucomLabel.Text = 'Comprimento sucção(m)';

            % Create Comprimento_suc
            app.Comprimento_suc = uieditfield(app.TubulaoButtonGroup, 'numeric');
            app.Comprimento_suc.Position = [9 169 179 22];
            app.Comprimento_suc.Value = 1;

            % Create ComprimentorecalquemLabel
            app.ComprimentorecalquemLabel = uilabel(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.ComprimentorecalquemLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.ComprimentorecalquemLabel.Position = [8 144 180 22];
            app.ComprimentorecalquemLabel.Text = 'Comprimento recalque(m)';

            % Create Comprimento_recalque
            app.Comprimento_recalque = uieditfield(app.TubulaoButtonGroup, 'numeric');
            app.Comprimento_recalque.Position = [8 122 180 22];

            % Create DiametrodoatuadorinLabel
            app.DiametrodoatuadorinLabel = uilabel(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.DiametrodoatuadorinLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.DiametrodoatuadorinLabel.Position = [8 93 180 22];
            app.DiametrodoatuadorinLabel.Text = 'Diametro do atuador(in)';

            % Create Diametro_atuador
            app.Diametro_atuador = uieditfield(app.TubulaoButtonGroup, 'numeric');
            app.Diametro_atuador.Position = [8 71 180 22];

            % Create DiametrohastedoatuadorinLabel
            app.DiametrohastedoatuadorinLabel = uilabel(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.DiametrohastedoatuadorinLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.DiametrohastedoatuadorinLabel.Position = [8 41 180 22];
            app.DiametrohastedoatuadorinLabel.Text = 'Diametro haste do atuador(in)';

            % Create Diametro_haste_do_atuador
            app.Diametro_haste_do_atuador = uieditfield(app.TubulaoButtonGroup, 'numeric');
            app.Diametro_haste_do_atuador.Position = [8 19 180 22];

            % Create Switch
            app.Switch = uiswitch(app.TubulaoButtonGroup, 'slider');
            app.Switch.Items = {'0', '1'};
            app.Switch.FontColor = [0.9412 0.9412 0.9412];
            app.Switch.Position = [70 427 45 20];
            app.Switch.Value = '0';

            % Create PVC_Label
            app.PVC_Label = uilabel(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.PVC_Label.HorizontalAlignment = 'right';
            app.PVC_Label.Position = [35 426 30 22];
            app.PVC_Label.Text = 'PVC';

            % Create Metal_Label
            app.Metal_Label = uilabel(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.Metal_Label.HorizontalAlignment = 'right';
            app.Metal_Label.Position = [114 426 35 22];
            app.Metal_Label.Text = 'Metal';

            % Create DiametrodatubulaoinDropDownLabel
            app.DiametrodatubulaoinDropDownLabel = uilabel(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.DiametrodatubulaoinDropDownLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'right';
            app.DiametrodatubulaoinDropDownLabel.Position = [17 399 147 22];
            app.DiametrodatubulaoinDropDownLabel.Text = 'Diametro da tubulação (in)';

            % Create DiametrodatubulaoinDropDown
            app.DiametrodatubulaoinDropDown = uidropdown(app.TubulaoButtonGroup);
            app.DiametrodatubulaoinDropDown.Items = {'0.75', '1', '1.25', '1.5', '2', '2.5', '3', '4', '5'};
            app.DiametrodatubulaoinDropDown.Position = [48 378 100 22];
            app.DiametrodatubulaoinDropDown.Value = '0.75';

            % Create PerdasdecargaButtonGroup
            app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup = uibuttongroup(app.DadosdeentradaButtonGroup);
            app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup.Title = 'Perdas de carga';
            app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup.Position = [392 0 170 481];

            % Create Spinner
            app.Spinner = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner.Position = [108 431 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_2
            app.Spinner_2 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_2.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_2.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_2.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_2.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_2.Position = [108 400 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_3
            app.Spinner_3 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_3.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_3.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_3.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_3.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_3.Position = [108 369 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_4
            app.Spinner_4 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_4.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_4.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_4.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_4.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_4.Position = [108 339 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_5
            app.Spinner_5 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_5.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_5.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_5.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_5.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_5.Position = [108 308 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_6
            app.Spinner_6 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_6.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_6.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_6.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_6.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_6.Position = [108 277 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_7
            app.Spinner_7 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_7.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_7.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_7.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_7.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_7.Position = [108 247 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_8
            app.Spinner_8 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_8.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_8.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_8.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_8.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_8.Position = [108 216 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_9
            app.Spinner_9 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_9.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_9.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_9.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_9.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_9.Position = [108 186 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_10
            app.Spinner_10 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_10.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_10.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_10.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_10.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_10.Position = [108 155 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_11
            app.Spinner_11 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_11.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_11.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_11.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_11.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_11.Position = [108 123 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_12
            app.Spinner_12 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_12.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_12.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_12.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_12.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_12.Position = [108 101 50 15];

            % Create Spinner_13
            app.Spinner_13 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_13.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_13.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_13.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_13.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_13.Position = [108 79 50 15];

            % Create Spinner_14
            app.Spinner_14 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_14.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_14.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_14.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_14.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_14.Position = [108 50 50 22];

            % Create Spinner_15
            app.Spinner_15 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_15.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_15.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_15.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_15.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_15.Position = [108 27 50 15];

            % Create Spinner_16
            app.Spinner_16 = uispinner(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Spinner_16.Limits = [0 Inf];
            app.Spinner_16.RoundFractionalValues = 'on';
            app.Spinner_16.ValueDisplayFormat = '%.0f';
            app.Spinner_16.HorizontalAlignment = 'center';
            app.Spinner_16.Position = [108 5 50 15];

            % Create Image
            app.Image = uiimage(app.PerdasdecargaButtonGroup);
            app.Image.Position = [1 1 104 457];
            app.Image.ImageSource = 'Captura de tela 2023-04-24 084824.png';

            % Create CalcularButton
            app.CalcularButton = uibutton(app.DadosdeentradaButtonGroup, 'push');
            app.CalcularButton.ButtonPushedFcn = createCallbackFcn(app, @Calcular, true);
            app.CalcularButton.Position = [245 30 100 22];
            app.CalcularButton.Text = 'Calcular';

            % Create EditFieldLabel
            app.EditFieldLabel = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.EditFieldLabel.HorizontalAlignment = 'right';
            app.EditFieldLabel.Position = [767 586 56 22];
            app.EditFieldLabel.Text = 'Edit Field';

            % Create EditField
            app.EditField = uieditfield(app.UIFigure, 'text');
            app.EditField.Position = [838 586 100 22];

            % Create EditField2Label
            app.EditField2Label = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.EditField2Label.HorizontalAlignment = 'right';
            app.EditField2Label.Position = [764 549 62 22];
            app.EditField2Label.Text = 'Edit Field2';

            % Create EditField2
            app.EditField2 = uieditfield(app.UIFigure, 'text');
            app.EditField2.Position = [841 549 100 22];

            % Create EditField3Label
            app.EditField3Label = uilabel(app.UIFigure);
            app.EditField3Label.HorizontalAlignment = 'right';
            app.EditField3Label.Position = [764 508 62 22];
            app.EditField3Label.Text = 'Edit Field3';

            % Create EditField3
            app.EditField3 = uieditfield(app.UIFigure, 'text');
            app.EditField3.Position = [841 508 100 22];

            % Show the figure after all components are created
            app.UIFigure.Visible = 'on';
        end
    end

    % App creation and deletion
    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = Sistemas

            % Create UIFigure and components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Designer distinguishes between an [EditField](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.control.editfield-properties.html), which contains text, and a [NumericEditField](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.control.numericeditfield-properties.html), which contains numeric values. You must either (a) convert your numeric value to text or (b) use a Numeric Edit Field.

Comment: I noticed that after posting but I dont understand how it would be related to defining my N variable that indicates the item inside the array, can u explain it? Or r u just pointing another error?

Comment: @ArthurFurtado You are trying to assign the value of the edit field, which expects text (as the error message indicates). The value stored in that edit field can only be characters/strings. The value of N is numeric (I'm assuming it is the type double).